# IDE for ExtJS4 with intelligence

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I am a beginner to ExtJS, and starting with Sencha Touch. Can you guys help me out in finding some good sites and best IDE's to use. I have gone through the below link  [ides-plugins-and-tools-for-ext-js-20](http://www.sencha.com/blog/ides-plugins-and-tools-for-ext-js-20). but it looks like i am able to get it done with installing Spket IDE in eclipse, but it doesn't give me code intelligence.

Comment: I have   doubt, If you have chat permission [look this](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7451/extjs-3-x-4-x-java-script-framework)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the WebStorm and check this thread http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?148220-What-tools-do-you-use-for-development